# Regex python para encontrar todos os valores com math na moeda brasileira

Tags: python, regex

Preciso de uma regex para encontrar todos os valores monetários do brasil, já fiz varias pesquisas e teste mas não consegui chegar a um resultado satisfatório.

```
1.566.545,00 = True
154.565,00 = True
22.555,00 = True
1.550,00 = True
11,10 = True
1100 = false


regex utilizada: '\d{0,}\W{0,}\d{1,}\d{0,}\W{0,}\d{0,}\,{0,1}\d{0,}'
```

Comment: *"já fiz varias pesquisas e teste ..."* coloca na pergunta o que já tentou e o que está errado, assim fica mais fácil de alguém sugerir uma correção

Comment: Inclui a regex utilizada

Comment: humm isso da muito trabalho (do jeito que está ai), poderia fazer algo assim "veja se a cada ponto existe um grupo de 3 digitos a seguir", que ficaria assim `(.\d{3})` ou seja, se houver um ponto precisa precer um grupo de 3 digitos, assim faz isso uma vez apenas

Comment: *não consegui chegar a um resultado satisfatório* nesse caso o que é um resultado satisfatório?

Comment: Entendi, vou fazer alguns teste pra ver

Comment: @AugustoVasques posso ter me expressado mal, um resultado satisfatório seria dar True nos valores informados

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\d{0,}` significa "zero ou mais dígitos", então se não tiver nenhum dígito, também vai encontrar um *match*.

Enfim, um valor monetário da forma que você quer segue as seguintes regras:

- pode ter até 3 dígitos iniciais
- depois, pode ter um ponto seguido de mais 3 dígitos, e isso pode se repetir várias vezes (ou nenhuma)
- sempre termina com vírgula e dois dígitos

Uma primeira tentativa seria:

```py
import re

regex = re.compile(r'^\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*,\d{2}$')

valores = ['1.566.545,00', '154.565,00', '22.555,00', '1.550,00', '11,10', '1100']
for v in valores:
    print(f'{v} = {bool(regex.match(v))}')
```

Usei os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que indicam o início e final da string, assim eu garanto que ela só tem o que está na regex.

- `\d{1,3}` quer dizer "no mínimo 1 e no máximo 3 dígitos"
- Depois temos um ponto, seguido de exatamente 3 dígitos (o `{3}` indica que são exatamente 3). Tudo isso está entre parênteses e com o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`, que significa "zero ou mais vezes" (é o mesmo que `{0,}`). Ou seja, o ponto seguido de 3 dígitos pode se repetir várias vezes (ou nenhuma)
- Depois temos a vírgula e mais dois dígitos

A saída do código acima é:

```
1.566.545,00 = True
154.565,00 = True
22.555,00 = True
1.550,00 = True
11,10 = True
1100 = False
```

---

Mas isso ainda não trata alguns casos, como por exemplo `012,12` - deveria começar com zero? Os únicos casos que talvez pudessem começar com zero seria `0,15` ou `0,00` por exemplo. Se for o caso, aí já começa a complicar. Teria que ser algo como:

```py
regex = re.compile(r'^((?!0)\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*|0),\d{2}$')
```

Agora usei [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`, que significa "ou"). E ela tem duas alternativas:

- `(?!0)\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*`: o trecho `(?!0)` é um [*lookahead* negativo](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), que verifica se não tem um zero à frente. O restante é o que já vimos acima (os dígitos e as sequências de ponto + 3 dígitos). Ou seja, esta sequência não pode começar com zero.
- `0`: é um único dígito zero

Isso quer dizer que, ou tem um zero e logo depois a vírgula, ou tem vários dígitos, desde que o primeiro não seja zero.

Depois disso temos a vírgula e os dois dígitos. Com isso, a regex aceita valores como `0,00` e `0,15`, mas rejeita `00,00` e `012,12`.

Comment: `regex = re.compile(r'^((?!0)\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*|0),\d{2}$')` essa aqui funcionou exatamente como eu precisava. Muito obrigado pela ajuda! e pela explicação